# Curlies in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to understand the usage of curlies below and values in it

Method:

```
def tester(value) 
  return value + 1 
end
```

Method usage:

```
value = tester(10) { 
  {"matcher" => "done"} 
}
```

what is the use of having `{ "matcher" => "done" }`, is this a block?

Comment: Is it the actual code ? because nested curlies don't seem to mean anything to me. `{"matcher" => "done"}` is just a hash though. With "matcher" being the key and "done" the value. It's just what's outside this hash which I am not familiar with

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet is valid ruby code, it does a call to `tester` method with a parameter of `10` and a block `{ { "matcher" => "done" } }`. This block just returns the hash (as the last statement is always returned in ruby) that has a key of `matcher` with the value of `done`. If you use the method you defined, the block can be omitted as it's not used for anything.

If you want to do something with the passed block, you could do:

```rb
def tester(value)
  hash = yield

  hash['tester'] = value
  hash
end
```

This returns the following hash:

```rb
{ 'matcher' => 'done', 'tester' => 10 }
```

Blocks can be explicit and implicit, [here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) you can find more information. Also I would recommend to experience with different syntaxes and bahaviours by booting up `irb`.